# doing inner joins on the first row of the table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I have an entity which is called Product. Product has an array of ProductPicture.
Here's a snippet of the code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Site\MainBundle\Entity\ProductPicture", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
protected $pictures;
```

So I have the following query doctrine DQL query:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p.id, p.name, pictures.name')
            ->from("SiteMainBundle:Product", 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
            ->innerJoin('p.pictures', 'pictures');
```

What this does is that it does an inner join with every single row of pictures (because each product has manu picture), and hence if I generate a json out of this, it will return something like this:

```
[{"id":346,"name":"11b650390dde2f3132875c2f265490040ce00d93.jpg"},
 {"id":346,"name":"98c03f5e7896cf22143f5303f8fa54e7cb6a42d5.jpg"},
 {"id":346,"name":"776c975ed78091fbdaaf0fceac90115258b822a0.jpg"},
 {"id":346,"name":"b02f44ff728d0ca7b498038bfd331a364eb712a3.jpg"},
 {"id":346,"name":"eccc317200ba6b3c01fd1815bd29ebac0b96f16a.jpg"}]
```

I only wanted this to be inner joined with the first `ProductPicture` in the array and not all and so it would generate something like this:

```
[{"id":346,"name":"11b650390dde2f3132875c2f265490040ce00d93.jpg"}];
```

Bottom hand is that I don't need all of the `ProductPicture`, I only need the first one.

Just for illustration purpose I have a method called `getCover` in the Product entity that gets the first `ProductPicture` in the array:

```
/** 
 * @Accessor(getter="getCover") 
 */
private $cover;
public function getCover()
{
    if($this->pictures->count() > 0) {
        return $this->pictures[0];
    }
    return new ProductPicture();
}
```

This is exactly what I want the inner join to be performed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of ...

```
getQueryBuilder()-> /*...*/ ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

or ( doesn't throw Exception if no result ) ...

```
getQueryBuilder()-> /*...*/ ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult()
```

or ...

```
getQueryBuilder()-> /*...*/ ->getQuery()->fetchOne()->getResult();
```

or ( dirty - will result in array, access with [0] , but probably what you want ) ...

```
getQueryBuilder()-> /*...*/ ->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getResult();
```